# AS3: MovieClip higher than set mask

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, masking

I have this annoying problem with masks and height om movieclips. I don't know whether it's just how Flash behaves or if I'm missing something.

I have a movieclip with a prefilled content (some simple vector graphic in a movieclip), with the height of 40. I then apply a mask to it, with the height of 30. Now i would think that the MovieClip is 30 pixel high, but it turns out to be 40 pixel high!?!

Is there some property im not setting or does the movieclip always assume the height of ALL the content within it? or what?

Actually in another clip, too, I have predefined 2 vector graphics (in two seperate movieclips), where the highest one is applied as a mask to the second graphic. The movieclip again assumes the height of the highest element. That might be logical, as it is the mask, BUT! when i then resize my mask (programatically) the height of the movieclip remains the same!?!?

Is there some way to recalculate the height of a movie clip? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the MovieClip size is the bounding rectangle around all its content, with no consideration for which clips within could be masks.

If you want to know the size of the visible masked area, why not give the MovieClip *that is the mask* an instance name and use its width, height and position for your layout purposes?

Comment: Well I was hoping for a less cumbersome solution :) I have several MovieClips inside a Container MovieClip and i wanted to just measure the height of that container. But i guess i just have to save the height of the nested movieclip masks :)

Comment: If you're setting the mask in code using DisplayObject.mask, then you already have the reference you need. Instead of using myClip.width, use myClip.mask.width to get the width. It's not that cumbersome, but you do need to manage the offset of the mask from the content, so that you get the desired area showing.